# Codesys fatek programming

Tags: plc, codesys

How can I write a program in codesys (ST or IL) and put it on fatek FBs series PLC? It is posible? I was not using codesys before. I was using Ladder and other PLCs (Omron, Unitronics, Simens, Schnider Electric).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to program a PLC with CodeSys, CodeSys RT (Runtime) has to be installed to the controller.

This RT environment acts as tiny OS. It includes all libraries and executables. For example you use function TON in your ST PRG. In order to execute it, there should be a library that define this function.

CoDeSys RT is made to support all [IEC 61131-3 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_61131-3) which includes support for all ST, LD, SFC, CFC, FBD, IL. CodeSys RT is also licensed. So if PLC developer wants their controllers to be programmed with CoDeSys, they purchase 1000 licenses and install RT on 1000 PLCs.

So as you can see, it is impossible to use other languages than one provided by FATEK.

Comment: I found documentation for Fatek Communication Protocol, and how to send new program to PLC. So I will make my own internal program for programming. Thanks.

Comment: Actually the TON function is not in the Runtime, CODESYS compiler converts this into a binary and runs on the application.

Comment: @vcberta Yes I know? All standard functions are in the standard library which comes with CoDeSys. It is not in runtime, but for example, function TIME() that is used in timers like TON is in runtime. This is what I basically mean. That runtime is needed to support your basic functionality.

Comment: yes thats correct, i missundertood I thought you meant the implementation of TON done at a runtime level.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I knew, there is no any Fatek PLCs based on CoDeSys system.

For this reason, it's impossible to write program in CoDeSys to control them.

You only can use their own software as WinProladder.

[Downloading website](http://www.fatek.com/en/technical.php?act=software&catId=10)

Comment: Oh, ok, is there another tool for programming it in IL or ST? WinProladder is for Ledder only?

Comment: BTW very crappy one (WinProladder). I've tried it and I hate it.

Answer (score 0):

All the Fatek PLC's just has ladder functionalities.

As far as I know there is no tool to convert Ladder code ST. 
Unfortunately, you can just use ladder on Fatek.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have the codesys RT installed in the target and this will handle all the interactions with the underlining interfaces and drivers. Codesys RT doens`t only execute on system with an OS but also on embedded devices. With some targets you can actually purchase the codesys RT license (i.e. raspberry) and then to install it yourself, with commercial devices this is normally done at the factory when this is sold, as there are several different types of licenses (RT, visu, webvisu) with different pricing.
Codesys is not an open-source and you will need to pay for the licensing, either yourself or this will be passed through the manufacturer added on top of the cost of the hardware.